# How to set Flyway migration file location using Spring profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway, spring-profiles

I have two Spring profiles `dev` and `test` configured for development and test environment. And in each environment I am using different databases viz `h2` in dev and `postgresql` in testing. Following are my properties files for each profile where `{vendor}` is resolved by spring boot to `h2` and `postgresql` repectively as per datasource configured.

application-dev.properties

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/{vendor}
```

application-test.properties

```
#Data source
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

#Flyway
spring.flyway.check-location=false
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration/test/{vendor}
```

Flyway migration files for `dev` profile are under `test/resources` and for `test` profile under `main/resources`

[image]

[image]

This is working fine when I run my application with `test` profile where it picks migration files only under `main/resources`. However, When I run my unit test using `dev` profile. I expect it to pick files only under `src/test/resources/db/migration/h2`. But Flyway is picking up migration files from `main/resources` and `test/resources` both leading to error

> org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found more than one migration with version 1

I don't understand this behavior. Any inputs on how to fix this?

Answer (score 14):

So, here is how I did it.

Requirements:

1. Use Spring profiles to configure application for different environments viz `dev`, `test` and `prod`.
2. Use Spring profiles to load flyway migration files as per the environment.

Database per environement:

1. `H2` database for `dev` environment.
2. `postgresql` database for `test` environment.
3. `postgresql` database for `prod` environment.

Configuration

1. Create Spring profiles `dev`, `test` and `prod` in *pom.xml*.

   `<profiles>
       <profile>
           <id>dev</id>
           <activation>
               <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
           </activation>
       </profile>
       <profile>
           <id>test</id>
       </profile>
       <profile>
           <id>prod</id>
       </profile>
   </profiles>`
2. Create properties files for each profile

*application-dev.properties*

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/{vendor}
```

Since, `H2` database is configured by Spring boot when *H2* driver is on classpath. We don't need to configure it explicitly.

*application-test.properties*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.flyway.locations=/db/{vendor}/common,/db/{vendor}/test
```

*application-prod.properties*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_prod
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.flyway.locations=/db/{vendor}/common,/db/{vendor}/prod
```

3. Flyway migration file locations.

If you will notice, I have not used `db/migration` under `src/main/resources` to place migration files which is the default location. For simple reason that Flyway picks all the files under this location and which results in version conflict between files for different environments. For e.g `V2__data_insertion.sql` is present for all three environments and this will not work if these were nested under `db/migration`. Since, `H2` migration files pertain to default profile I have left them at the default flyway migration file location.

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

Its not about the flyway only.

In maven there are two different classpathes that it works with during the build:

1. Compile classpath - used for compilation (including `src/main/*`)
2. Testing classpath - effectively including both `src/test/*` (obviously) and `src/main/*` because in tests you should have a compile time access to the actual code.

That's why in runtime there are effectively 2 accessible places and flyway finds more than one migration.

Another observation:

Your production code in general should not include anything about tests. But I see that you add: `src/main/resources/application-test.properties` This file will appear in the production artifact which is wrong.

As a workaround you can work with 
`src/main/resources/application-prod.properties` that defines location "X" for real migrations
As opposed to:
`src/test/resources/application-test.properties` that defines location "Y" for test migrations
Run integration tests with Profile Test and you won't find production migrations.